# How do I check the number of bytes consumed by a structure?

Tags: c#, .net, byte

If I am creating a relatively large structure, how can I calculate the bytes it occupies in memory?

We can do it manually, but if the struct is large enough then how do we do it? Is there some code chunk or application?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use either the [`sizeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx) operator or [`SizeOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof.aspx) function.
There are some differences between those options, see the reference links for more.

Anyway a good way to use that function is to have a generic method or extension method like these:

```
static class Test
{
  static void Main()
  {
    //This will return the memory usage size for type Int32:
    int size = SizeOf<Int32>();

    //This will return the memory usage size of the variable 'size':
    //Both lines are basically equal, the first one makes use of ex. methods
    size = size.GetSize();
    size = GetSize(size);
  }

  public static int SizeOf<T>()
  {
    return System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
  }

  public static int GetSize(this object obj)
  {
    return System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(obj);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that the `Marshal.SizeOf()` method should be used instead of the `sizeof()` keyword? Writing `sizeof(int)` is not only more effeicient than `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T))`, since it incurs no runtime cost, but it also is easier to read. `Marshal.SizeOf()` should only be used for types meant for use in unmanaged scenarios (such as P/Invoke).

Comment: +1 but beware that this returns unmanaged size, which may or may not equal the managed size. Doesn't sound like that matters to the OP, though. Also, `sizeof` is fine since .NET 2.0, since it no longer requires `unsafe`.

Comment: @Kent, right, but since the sizeof operator is naturally unmanaged (unlike the SizeOf method that is wrapped with managed code), it still has some restrictions, for example, it won't accept an unknown (i.e. generic) type where it doesn't have a predefined size.
So for instance, the generic SizeOf function in my above example, cannot be implemented with the sizeof operator.

Comment: The `sizeof` operator still requires an `unsafe` context. The exception beginning with .NET 2.0 was to allow it to be used on the CTS types.

Comment: So anycase is safer to use the SizeOf function, also you can the use it against any CLR generic type.

Comment: @ Allon Guralnek,@Kent Boogaart,@Shimmy,@Brian Gideon
Can you please explain what is Managed and Umanaged Code,Size and Memory.I have asked the same question at the follwoing URL:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368802/what-is-the-diference-in-managed-and-umanaged-code-memory-and-size

Comment: @Subhen, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/a3e28547-4791-4394-b450-29c82cd70f70/

Comment: Note that Marshal.SizeOf won't work on a generic type (generic class or struct, or a class or struct nested inside a generic type), but it will work on an instance of a generic type. For generics, the GetSize method above works, but SizeOf<T> will throw "System.ArgumentException: The specified Type must not be a generic type definition."

Answer (score 113):

Structs have been troublesome beasts in computer engineering for a very long time.  Their memory layout is very hardware dependent.  To make them efficient, their members must be aligned so the CPU can read and write their values quickly without having to multiplex the bytes to fit the memory bus width.  Every compiler has its own strategy of packing the members, often directed by, for example, the #pragma pack directive in a C or C++ program.

Which is okay, but rather a problem in interop scenarios.  Where one chunk of code may make different assumptions about the structure layout than another chunk, compiled by a different compiler.  You can see this back in COM, .NET's grandfather solution to interop programming.  COM has *very* poor support for handling structs.  It doesn't support them as a native automation type but has a workaround through the IRecordInfo interface.  Which lets a program discover the memory layout at runtime through an explicit declaration of the structure in a type library.  Which works okay, but is quite inefficient.

The .NET designers made a very courageous, and correct, decision to solve this problem.  They made the memory layout of a struct completely undiscoverable.  There is no documented way to retrieve the offset of a member.  And by extension, no way to discover the size of the struct.  Everybody's favorite answer, use Marshal.SizeOf() is not in fact the solution.  That returns the size of struct *after it is marshaled*, the size you'd need to pass to, say, Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem() before you call Marshal.StructureToPtr.  That arranges and aligns the struct members according to the [StructLayout] attribute that's associated with the struct.  Note that this attribute isn't required for structs (like it is for classes), the runtime implements a default one which uses the declared order for the members.

One very nice side-effect of the layout being undiscoverable is that the CLR can play tricks with it.  When packing the members of the struct and aligning them, the layout can get holes that don't store any data.  Called padding bytes.  Given that the layout is undiscoverable, the CLR can actually use the padding.  It moves a member if it is small enough to fit such a hole.  You'll now actually get a struct whose size is *smaller* than what would normally be required given the declared structure layout.  And, notably, Marshal.SizeOf() will return the *wrong* value for the structure size, it returns a value that's too large.

Long story short, there's no general way to get an accurate value for the structure size programmatically.  The best thing to do is to just not ask the question.  Marshal.SizeOf() will give you a guesstimate, assuming the structure is blittable.  If you need an accurate value for some reason then you could look at the generated machine code of a method that declares a local variable of the structure type and compare it to the same method without that local variable.  You'll see the difference in the stack pointer adjustment, the "sub esp, xxx" instruction at the top of the method.  Of course, it will be architecture dependent, you'll typically get a larger structure in 64-bit mode.

Comment: @Hans: Are you saying that this only applies when using padding? Marshal.SizeOf() has never failed me and I don't use padding.

Comment: @0A0D: padding is applied completely automatic, you don't normally see it.  It is affected by the StructLayoutAttribute.Pack value for marshaled structures.  The CLR uses a packing of 8, I think, small odds for 4.

Comment: @Hans: What about struct's marshalled from C++ DLLs? I don't think this applies when using LayoutKind.Sequential. Per MSDN: "Indicates that the members of the type are to be laid out in unmanaged memory in the same order in which they appear in the managed type definition. " So the CLR shouldn't pad at all or the bits would be jumbled.

Comment: @0A0D: as long as your are marshaling unmanaged structs you only care about the unmanaged layout of them.  In which case Marshal.SizeOf() is fine and the default [StructLayout] usually gets the job done.  But Marshal.PtrToStructure() is required to get a managed version of it.  The P/Invoke marshaller does that automatically.

Comment: @Hans Passant, Thanks, But I am unsure and really curious to know the difference bettwen Managed and Un-Managed Code, Memory and Size. Asked the question at the following URL:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368802/what-is-the-difference-in-managed-and-unmanaged-code-memory-and-size

Comment: ⁺¹ for mentioning about `Marshal.SizeOf()` is not a solution. I am just met a problem that for unknown reasons the `SizeOf()` [in this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3278956/2388257) returns wrong size *(perhaps need to mention that I am using this function with a generic class)*, so in the end I was needed to add to a class my own function that returns a size of an object, and give the size as an argument.

Comment: I am just found why the `Marshal.SizeOf()` always returned a wrong size for me, I hope this fill up this collection of C# fails: the «Marshal.SizeOf()» couldn't be called on an array! My structure object has a few, so the function always returned a wrong size that much smaller of the real one.

Comment: While you can not find out about the memory layout of a Struct, it's still possible to define a memory layout with [StructLayout(LayoutKind..., Size)] and [FieldOffset(...)]  Having knowledge and control about the layout is sufficient in most cases :)

Answer (score 10):

You can either use the [`sizeof()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx) keyword for user-defined structs that do not contain any fields or properties that are reference types, or use the [`Marshal.SizeOf(Type)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/5s4920fa) or [`Marshal.SizeOf(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/y3ybkfb3) to obtain the unmanaged size of a type or a struct that has a sequential or explicit [layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06sb63ba.aspx).

Answer (score 9):

**0. For the example code:**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

**1. Demonstration struct**

```
[Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 128)]
public struct T
{
    public int a;
    public byte b;
    public int c;
    public String d;
    public short e;
};
```

**2. Subtracting managed pointers:**

> ```
> /// Return byte-offset between managed addresses of struct instances 'hi' and 'lo'
> public static long IL<T1,T2>.RefOffs(ref T1 hi, ref T2 lo) { ... }
> ```

```
public static class IL<T1, T2>
{
    public delegate long _ref_offs(ref T1 hi, ref T2 lo);

    public static readonly _ref_offs RefOffs;

    static IL()
    {
        var dm = new DynamicMethod(
            Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            typeof(long),
            new[] { typeof(T1).MakeByRefType(), typeof(T2).MakeByRefType() },
            typeof(Object),
            true);

        var il = dm.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Sub);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_I8);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        RefOffs = (_ref_offs)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(_ref_offs));
    }
};
```

**3. Reveal managed internal struct layout:**

```
static class demonstration
{
    /// Helper thunk that enables automatic type-inference from argument types
    static long RefOffs<T1,T2>(ref T1 hi, ref T2 lo) => IL<T1,T2>.RefOffs(ref hi, ref lo);

    public static void Test()
    {
        var t = default(T);
        var rgt = new T[2];

        Debug.Print("Marshal.Sizeof<T>: {0,2}", Marshal.SizeOf<T>());
        Debug.Print("&rgt[1] - &rgt[0]: {0,2}", RefOffs(ref rgt[1], ref rgt[0]));

        Debug.Print("int      &t.a      {0,2}", RefOffs(ref t.a, ref t));
        Debug.Print("byte     &t.b      {0,2}", RefOffs(ref t.b, ref t));
        Debug.Print("int      &t.c      {0,2}", RefOffs(ref t.c, ref t));
        Debug.Print("String   &t.d      {0,2}", RefOffs(ref t.d, ref t));
        Debug.Print("short    &t.e      {0,2}", RefOffs(ref t.e, ref t));
    }
};
```

**4. Results and Discussion**

The `StructLayout(..., Pack)` setting can be added to the declaration of `struct T` with any of the following values: **{ 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 }**. The default value when `Pack` is not specified—or equivalently with `Pack=0`—sets packing equal to `IntPtr.Size` (`4` on x86, `8` on x64).

The results of running the above program show that the `Pack` value only affects the *marshaling size* reported by `Marshal.SizeOf`, and not the actual size of a single `T` memory image, assumed to be the byte-offset between physically adjacent instances. The test code measures this via diagnostic managed array `new T[2]` assigned to *rgt*.

> `========= x86 ==========`     `========= x64 ==========`
>
> `-------- Pack=1 --------`     `-------- Pack=1 --------`
>   `Marshal.Sizeof():     15`     `Marshal.Sizeof():     19`
>   `&rgt[1] - &rgt[0]:    16`     `&rgt[1] - &rgt[0]:    24`
>
> `-------- Pack=2 --------`     `-------- Pack=2 --------`
>   `Marshal.Sizeof():     16`     `Marshal.Sizeof():     20`
>   `&rgt[1] - &rgt[0]:    16`     `&rgt[1] - &rgt[0]:    24`
>
> `--- Pack=4/0/default ---`     `-------- Pack=4 --------`
>   `Marshal.Sizeof():     20`     `Marshal.Sizeof():     24`
>   `&rgt[1] - &rgt[0]:    16`     `&rgt[1] - &rgt[0]:    24`
>   
>   `-------- Pack=8 --------`     `--- Pack=8/0/default ---`
>   `Marshal.Sizeof():     20`     `Marshal.Sizeof():     32`
>   `&rgt[1] - &rgt[0]:    16`     `&rgt[1] - &rgt[0]:    24`
>
> `-- Pack=16/32/64/128 ---`     `-- Pack=16/32/64/128 ---`
>   `Marshal.Sizeof():     20`     `Marshal.Sizeof():     32`
>   `&rgt[1] - &rgt[0]:    16`     `&rgt[1] - &rgt[0]:    24`

As noted, we find that per-architecture (**x86**, **x64**), the ***managed field layout*** is consistent regardless of `Pack` setting. Here are the actual managed field offsets, again for both 32- and 64-bit mode, as reported by the code above:

> `┌─offs─┐`
>   `field   type   size  x86  x64`
>   `=====  ======  ====  ===  ===`
>     `a    int        4    4    8`
>     `b    byte       1   14   18`
>     `c    int        4    8   12`
>     `d    String   4/8    0    0`
>     `e    short      2   12   16`

The most important thing to notice in this table is that, (as [mentioned by Hans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3362736/147511)), the reported field offsets are non-monotonic with respect to their declaration order. The fields of `ValueType` instances are always reordered so that all of the reference-typed fields go first. We can see that the `String` field *d* is at offset 0.

Further reordering optimizes the field order in order to share internal padding excess which would otherwise be wasted. We can see this with `byte` field *b*, which has been moved from being the second declared field, all the way to being the last.

Naturally, by sorting the rows of the previous table we can reveal the true internal managed layout of a **.NET** `ValueType`. Notice that we are able to obtain this layout despite the example struct `T` containing a managed reference (`String d`) and thus being ***non-blittable***:

> `============= x86 ============`     `============= x64 ============`
>   `field   type   size  offs  end`     `field   type   size  offs  end`
>   `=====  ======  ====  ====  ===`     `=====  ======  ====  ====  ===`
>     `d    String     4     0 …  4`       `d    String     8     0 …  8`
>     `a    int        4     4 …  8`       `a    int        4     8 … 12`
>     `c    int        4     8 … 12`       `c    int        4    12 … 16`
>     `e    short      2    12 … 14`       `e    short      2    16 … 18`
>     `b    byte       1    14 … 15`       `b    byte       1    18 … 19`
>
> `internal padding: 1    15 … 16`     `internal padding: 5    19 … 24`
>
> `x86 managed total size: 16`            `x64 managed total size: 24`

Earlier we determined the size of a single managed struct instance by computing the byte-offset difference between adjacent instances. Taking that into account, the last lines of the previous table trivially show the padding that the **CLR** internally applies to the end of the example struct `T`. Remember again of course, that this internal padding is fixed by the CLR and entirely beyond our control.

**5. Coda**
For completeness, this last table shows the amount of padding that will be synthesized *on-the-fly* during ***marshaling***. Notice that in some cases, this `Marshal` padding is negative versus the internal managed size. For example, even though the internal managed size of a `T` in **x64** is 24 bytes, the struct emitted by marshaling can be 19 or 20 bytes with `Pack=1` or `Pack=2`, respectively.

> `pack      size  offs  end`          `pack      size  offs  end`
>   `=============  ====  ====  ===`     `=============  ====  ====  ===`
>         `1           0    15 … 15`           `1           0    19 … 19`
>         `2           1    15 … 16`           `2           1    19 … 20`
>   `4/8/16/32/64…     5    15 … 20`     `4/8/16/32/64…     5    19 … 24`

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a tiny little library in [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) ([.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)'s assembly language) to expose some neat functionality that isn't available in C#. I broke out the `sizeof` instruction.

It differs significantly from the `sizeof` operator in C#. Basically, it gets the size of a structure (or reference type, which act funny with some optimizations) including padding and all. So, if you were to create an array of `T`, then you can use sizeof to determine the distance between each array element *in bytes*. It's also completely verifiable and managed code. Note that in [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29) there was a bug (pre-3.0?) which would cause the sizeof reference types to be reported incorrectly, which would expand to structures containing reference types.

Anyway, you can download the BSD licensed library (and CIL) [from BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/earlz/datastructures/src/4d07aca5ecdf7bf96f46992fa063e80cffda1e3d/BareMetal?at=default). You can also see some example code and a few more details [at my blog](http://lastyearswishes.com/blog/view/50a30d3bd1f1a5234323b198).

Answer (score 7):

In [.NET Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#.NET_Core), the `sizeof` CIL instruction has been exposed via the recently added `Unsafe` class. Add a reference to the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` package and just do this:

```
int size = Unsafe.SizeOf<MyStruct>();
```

It works for reference types as well (will return 4 or 8 depending on your computer's architecture).

Comment: You can define the Structs memory layout with [StructLayout(LayoutKind..., Size = ...)] and [FieldOffset(...)]  -what comes in handy in most cases. Just wanted to mention that.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s4920fa.aspx):

```
struct s
{
    public Int64 i;
}

public static void Main()
{
    s s1;
    s1.i = 10;          
    var s = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(s1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf()` to get the size in bytes as well.