# .NET DateTime Does Not Have a Predefined Size

Tags: .net, datetime, struct, size, sizeof

Since DateTime is a struct with members that appear to break down into simple mathematical values, I'm not sure why using sizeof() on it produces the message in the question title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the CLR can only determine the size at runtime... one of the reasons for this is "padding" (platform dependent)...

> For all other types, including structs, the sizeof operator can be
>   used only in unsafe code blocks. Although you can use the
>   Marshal.SizeOf method, the value returned by this method is not always
>   the same as the value returned by sizeof. Marshal.SizeOf returns the
>   size after the type has been marshaled, whereas sizeof returns the
>   size *as it has been allocated by the common language runtime,
>   including any padding*.

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx).

see also [How do I check the number of bytes consumed by a structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361986/how-to-check-the-number-of-bytes-consumed-by-my-structure)

Comment: Thanks :-) Added a second reference

Comment: This also implies that `sizeof(DateTime)` will work fine in `unsafe` context (see my new answer).

Comment: I don't think `Marshal.sizeof()` is necessary accurate in the cases where one needs to know the actual size of a type in managed code, such as when deciding how finely to subdivide a large collection to avoid Large Object Heap allocations.  The CIL opcode which `sizeof()` uses would actually work just fine with any managed type (the size of class-type storage locations would be reported as the size of an object reference, *which is precisely the information necessary needed for LOH avoidance*).  Unfortunately, the designers of C# decided programmers shouldn't have access to such information.

Answer (score 2):

The full error text you get, is:

> error CS0233: 'System.DateTime' does not have a predefined size, therefore
>   sizeof can only be used in an unsafe context (consider using
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf)

So if you do use `unsafe` context (be sure to go to the C# project's "Properties", the "Build" tab, and set a check mark in "Allow unsafe code" to make the below compile) it works fine:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        int s;
        unsafe
        {
            s = sizeof(DateTime);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(s); // writes 8
    }
```

With the `unsafe` keyword, `sizeof()` will work with all `enum` types and with all `struct` types that do not have instance fields of reference type (and `DateTime` is a struct with no reference type members, for sure).

Without the `unsafe` keyword, you cannot use `sizeof`. (However, since C# 2 you are allowed to use it on pre-defined types like `int` and on `enum` types, but not on other structs like `DateTime`, as you saw.)

---

Note that the `DateTime` struct is exceptional in that `Marshal.SizeOf<DateTime>()` (or `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DateTime))` prior to .NET version 4.5.1 (2013)) will throw an exception. This is because of the unusual (for a `struct`) structure layout "Auto".

Answer (score 0):

Alex Pinsker wrote [nice solution](http://alexpinsker.blogspot.cz/2011/10/what-is-size-of-datetime-type-in-c.html) for getting the size of `DateTime` (or any other type).