# Marshal.StructureToPtr fails with bool and fixed size array?

Tags: c#, marshalling

If I marshal this struct with `StructureToPtr` and then unmarshal it again with `PtrToStructure`, my first node has y = {1,2} whilst my second node has y = {1,0}.

I've no idea why, perhaps my struct is bad somehow? Removing the `bool` from the struct makes it work.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace csharp_test
{
    unsafe class Program
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct Node
        {
            public bool boolVar;
            public fixed int y[2];
        }

        unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Node node = new Node();

            node.y[0] = 1;
            node.y[1] = 2;
            node.boolVar = true;

            int size = sizeof(Node);
            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(node, ptr, false);
            Node node2 = (Node)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(Node));
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it has to do something with `bool` being marshaled as 4 bytes (`BOOL`) rather than 1 byte? But I can't think of the exact reason...

Comment: Moreover, it ignores any array elements after the first one (writes them as zeros into the unmanaged memory). It also doesn't matter if `bool` comes before the array or after in the structure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This indeed goes wrong.  It is the StructureToPtr() call that fails to copy enough bytes.  You can see this by using Debug + Windows + Memory + Memory1 and putting "ptr" in the address box.  Using the sizeof operator [isn't correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361986/how-to-check-the-number-of-bytes-consumed-by-my-structure/3362736#3362736) but not actually the source of the problem.  Only the first element of the array is copied, regardless of the array length.  Not sure what causes this problem, I never use *fixed* in pinvoke.  I can only recommend the traditional pinvoke way which works fine:

```
unsafe class Program {
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Node {
        public bool boolVar;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
        public int[] y;
    }

    unsafe static void Main(string[] args) {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.y = new int[2];

        node.y[0] = 1;
        node.y[1] = 2;
        node.boolVar = true;

        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(node);
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(node, ptr, false);
        Node node2 = (Node)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(Node));
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    }
```

You can post to connect.microsoft.com if you want to bring this to the attention of the CLR interop masters.

Comment: thanks, the comment in the link you post does indeed explain the problem, though actually the real answer is that I shouldn't be using fixed size buffers at all and should just use the MarshalAs attribute, as you demonstrate.

I was already aware that you shouldn't really use sizeof(), just I'm not sure whether in the real world it makes any difference. But anyway, I have now changed my code to use Marshal.SizeOf regardless.

Comment: @Hans a comments in your link are missing ☹

Comment: Just to add to this: PtrToStructure() will also only copy the first byte of the fixed array, even if the memory location contains more info. Even if the structure uses LayoutKind.Explicit it still fails :(

Answer (score 0):

You should also pack the struct or class before you use it. That works for me, almost as good as memcpy

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public class SomeClass
{
}
```