# Struct sizeof / Marshal.SizeOf variation

Tags: c#, struct, marshalling

I am trying to marshal a `struct` to a `byte[]` and then back again but am getting an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when marshaling back to `struct`. Here is the code:

```
public struct Response
{
    CommandNumber Command;
    ushort EstimatedRoundTripDuration;
}

protected TStruct ByteArrayToStruct<TStruct>(byte[] data) where TStruct : struct
{
    TStruct resp = new TStruct();
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(resp);
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

    try
    {
        Marshal.Copy(data, 0, ptr, size);
        Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, resp);

        return resp;
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr); //cleanup just in case
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be that `sizeof(Response)` is 3, whilst `Marshal.SizeOf(resp)` is 4. I understand that these can be and are expected to be different but im using fairly basic types for this `struct`. Can anyone shed any light on why the sizes are different?

Comment: They can be and are expected to be different.  Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361986/how-to-check-the-number-of-bytes-consumed-by-my-structure/3362736#3362736).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `CommandNumber` is one byte. As I recall, the interop layer likes to align data fields. So your `EstimatedRoundTripDuration` will be aligned to the next even address, leaving one byte of padding. So it would look like this:

```
Command: 1 byte
padding: 1 byte
EstimatedRoundTripDuration: 1 byte
```

You can change the marshaling behavior with the [StructLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
public struct Response
{
    CommandNumber Command;
    ushort EstimatedRoundTripDuration;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to change the enumeration to byte, but yes it is 8bit. I'm assuming this 'even byte' padding is based upon the word size of my system (64bit) - is that correct? The StructLayout attribute alone did not help. I have to change the Pack property to 1.

Comment: @Gusdor: The "even byte" padding will occur on a 32-bit machine, as well. I don't know all the rules of the default packing. You'll have to look up the documentation for Pack, and possibly do a bit more research than that.