# How to get size of class / struct object in C#

Tags: c#, sizeof

How to get size of an object of a class/struct in C#.

```
hello h = new hello();
Base b = new Base();
Console.Write(Marshal.SizeOf(h) + "," + Marshal.SizeOf(b));
Console.Read();
```

I tried above code, but it gives error. ERROR:

> *Type 'Virtual.Base' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.*

THanks!

Comment: Take at look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361986/how-to-check-the-number-of-bytes-consumed-by-my-structure

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207592/getting-the-size-of-a-field-in-bytes-with-c-sharp#207605

Comment: In general the "size" of a class is an implementation detail of the framework used. For example they could make it depend on the CPU architecture. What do you need the size for? Do you wish a memory profile of your program?