# Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)) vs sizeof(IntPtr)

Tags: c#, .net

I know how fundamentally different `Marshal.SizeOf()` and `sizeof()` are. But in the case of an `IntPtr`, won't they both **always** return exactly the same thing regardless of CPU architecture?

Comment: Do you mean what it's always either `4` (32x) or `8` (64x)? You are just lucky what `IntPtr` structure doesn't need [more managed memory](https://ericlippert.com/2013/06/13/whats-the-difference-sizeof-and-marshal-sizeof/), but it may someday or on some platform, better keep using the appropriate one.

Comment: Can you explain why you care whether the in-memory size and the on-wire size of something is the same?  Are you just asking a trivia question, or is there some purpose to your question?

Comment: @EricLippert the point was mainly to figure out whether, specifically with `IntPtr` in mind, `Marshal.SizeOf()` and `sizeof()` are interchangeable. And if not, why one would use one over the other.

Comment: Wait, you said **I know how fundamentally different they are** in the question. If you think that they might be interchangeable and don't know when you would use one or the other, then in what sense do you know how they are different?

Comment: Suppose I had a function that tells me how much counter space a toaster takes up, and another function that tells me how big a box I need to mail my toaster.  Does it make any sense at all to ask "for this particular toaster, are those two sizes the same?"  Maybe they are and maybe they aren't, but *why would you care*?  You'd use the first method when laying out a kitchen and the second method when packing a mail truck, and you'd *never* swap them because that would be a really bad idea.

Comment: @EricLippert you're answering the question of "why should I use `Marshal.SizeOf()` instead of `sizeof()`", when the question is limited to `IntPtr`. Simply put, I've seen examples of PInvokes that use `sizeof(IntPtr)` and others that use `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr))`. The question is whether as far as `IntPtr` one is _guaranteed_ that they will always end up being the same. If one is guaranteed that they are the same then those examples would be correct, even if you disagree with the approach. If they are not guaranteed to always be equal then the examples are just plain wrong.

Comment: No, the code would be wrong regardless.  Code can work and still be wrong; code which works *by accident* is wrong code. Approach coding as an engineering discipline, and follow good practices always.

Comment: If one is _guaranteed_ that `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr))` and `sizeof(IntPtr)` are *always* the same then it doesn't seem to me like characterising any code using the latter as just working "by accident" is fair... Not following good practices, sure. But working by accident when there's an assurance that it will behave as expected... not really.

Comment: I'm not following your train of thought. The person who wrote the wrong code did so either by accident, out of ignorance, or maliciously, to be deliberately misleading and confusing. If the former, then the person wrote a working program by luck; if the latter, then the person wrote a working program in order to fool the reader. The former seems about a million times more likely than the latter. Is there a third option other than ignorance or malice that I'm missing?

Comment: Your premise appears to be that it would be wrong to use `sizeof(<type>)` in PInvokes because one is not guaranteed (at least for other types) that it will return the same as `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(<type>))`. But like I said, **if** one is _guaranteed_ that, at least for `IntPtr` this will always be the case, then it seems to me that it's just a best practice, consistency and convention - not necessarily something that "is wrong" or that it would just work because of "dumb luck". Not that I'm advocating using sizeof, but just saying.

Comment: Anyway, the point of the question was to understand whether they will or not always return the same. I don't want to engage in a debate of whether method A or method B should be used, that's outside the scope of the discussion. And down voting because of some perceived idea that that's what the question is about is just plain wrong. The marked answer states that it is theoretically possible for them to differ and that answers the question. Anything else is just irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, why do you want to know? If your code is well-written, you should have no need for any assumptions about what `sizeof` and `Marshal.SizeOf` return. Will you be using the marshaller to marshal any of your `IntPtr` instances? Then use `Marshal.SizeOf`. Is your variable never leaving the managed world or are you using custom marshalling? Then use `sizeof` (or `IntPtr.Size` since it requires no `unsafe` block). In neither case will you be concerned with whether these return the same value. That's the practical answer.

On to the theory. According to the [C# language specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029), the value returned for `sizeof(IntPtr)` is "the total number of bytes in a variable of that type, including any padding" (since `IntPtr` is a structure). However, it also notes that this value is "implementation-defined". So, if you want to get technical, the C# spec simply says "figure it out".

That said, the documentation for `IntPtr` makes it clear that the type is 32-bit on 32-bit platforms and 64-bit on 64-bit platforms, and [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) documents that `IntPtr` is a special built-in type that corresponds to a `native int`, so I think we're allowed to tentatively conclude that `sizeof(IntPtr)` is predictable on any implementation that claims to follow the specifications: 4 on 32-bit platforms, 8 on 64-bit platforms. `IntPtr.Size` is an alternative, and it explicitly documents just that.

`Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr))` is a different beast. It doesn't document exactly what it will return other than "the size of the unmanaged type"; under water, it invokes a bit of native code in the CLR that asks the `TypeHelper` for the underlying type for the size. For `IntPtr`, this will return `sizeof(void*)` (in C++), which is, of course, 4 on 32-bit platforms and 8 on 64-bit platforms for the vast majority of C++ compilers and platforms.

It is technically, theoretically, possible for `sizeof(IntPtr)` and `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr))` to be different. But this is not something you'd concern yourself with in general, because it wouldn't be sensible for the combination of runtime and jitter (or AOT compiler) to not make `sizeof(IntPtr)` equal to `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr))` -- otherwise the runtime is just making its own life more difficult. On the other hand, as I pointed out, there's not typically any reason why you would need to *rely* on them being the same either.

Answer (score 6):

For one thing, there's the primitive types:

> `|           x64           |           x86`          
>              `|   Marshal.              |   Marshal.`             
>   `Primitive  | SizeOf<T>()  sizeof(T)  | SizeOf<T>()  sizeof(T)` 
>   `=========  | =========== =========== | =========== ===========`
>     `Boolean  |     4     <->    1      |      4    <->    1`     
>        `Byte  |     1            1      |      1           1`     
>       `SByte  |     1            1      |      1           1`     
>       `Int16  |     2            2      |      2           2`     
>      `UInt16  |     2            2      |      2           2`     
>       `Int32  |     4            4      |      4           4`     
>      `UInt32  |     4            4      |      4           4`     
>       `Int64  |     8            8      |      8           8`     
>      `UInt64  |     8            8      |      8           8`     
>      `IntPtr  |     8            8     <->     4           4`     
>     `UIntPtr  |     8            8     <->     4           4`     
>        `Char  |     1     <->    2      |      1    <->    2`     
>      `Double  |     8            8      |      8           8`     
>      `Single  |     4            4      |      4           4`

Beyond this, for struct (`ValueType`) instances in **.NET** there can be significant differences between the internal managed layout and the marshaling image, both in total size and also the field layout ordering. The latter is true even for so-called [*formatted classes*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zhzfk83(v=vs.110).aspx).<sup>[1]</sup>

It's rare to actually need information about the actual managed struct layout, and in fact **.NET** goes to great lengths in trying to make it undiscoverable. You also can't influence the internal layout of structs, and that's precisely why the `Marshal` layer provides the ability to specifically declare whatever layout you need for interop.

Here's one use case for needing to know the true size of a struct's runtime memory image: Let's say you are using managed arrays of structs for some kind of storage blob concept and you want each chunk (array, that is) to stay under a fixed total allocation size, say ~84,800 bytes--obviously in this case to stay out of the [LOH](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/maoni/2016/05/31/large-object-heap-uncovered-from-an-old-msdn-article/). You want this storage class to be a generic class, parameterized with an arbitrary `ValueType` type which defines the 'records' or table entries. To determine the number of structs that can go into each managed array chunk, you'd need to discover the true size of the structure given at runtime, so you can divide 84,800 by that value.

For a more detailed examination of the differences that can arise between ***marshaling*** versus ***managed-internal*** struct layout, padding, and size, please see my extended answer to "[How do I check the number of bytes consumed by a structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47951125/147511)"

---

[1.] "A *formatted class* is a reference type whose layout is specified by the StructLayoutAttribute attribute, as either [LayoutKind.Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind(v=vs.110).aspx) or [LayoutKind.Sequential](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind(v=vs.110).aspx)."
<sub>https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zhzfk83(v=vs.110).aspx</sub>